# Function calculation logarit

Tags: c++, c

I write my program calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cal(int a, int b){
    if (a == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (a == 1){
        return b;
    }
    else{
        int c = a / b;
        return (cal(a, c) + 1);
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Enter values: ");
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", cal(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

But when I runing my program. I have an error.
So. my program wrong or what problem with programming C, C++?
Thanks for view my question.

Comment: `I have a(n) error`..kindly share.

Comment: HINT --> : `int c = a / b;` what if `b` is `0`?

Comment: Please specify if you are programming in C or in C++.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh but when I change it. It can't call Function cal again. Example: a = 2, b =8. Result = 2. So can you guid to me how to write it? Thanks verry much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fine! Thanks for everyone. This is my fail.
I change my program same:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cal(int a, int b){
    if (a == 0){

        return 0;
    }
    else if (a == 1){
        return b;
    }
    else if (b == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (b == 1){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return (cal(a, b/a) + 1);
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Enter values: ");
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", cal(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int c = a / b;
```

Will give you a runtime error if you do not check that `b` is not allowed to be `0`.
Add a condition to verify that `b` is in fact not `0` and if it is, do not perform the division operation.

Comment: when I change it. It can't call Function cal again. Example: a = 2, b =8. Result = 2. So can you guid to me how to write it? Thanks verry much!

Comment: @NguyễnVănDũng what logic exactly you want from your program is yours to determine, but generally speaking, you can not divide by zero, ever.

Answer (score 0):

You run into an infinite recursion. It looks as if you had a termination condition, but the exits without recursion check on `a`, which will always be the same in your calls.

As is, your algorithm calls `cal(a, b)` and `cal(a, a / b)` respectively in odd and even recursion steps. Eventually, you run out of stack.

Revise your algorithm so that deeper recursions progress towards a base state, whcih you should check.

If you want to calculate the logarithm of `a` to the base `b`, you should keep the base `b` constant across calls and sucessively divide `a` by the base until you reach the case where the value `a` falls below the base:

```
int intlog(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b) return 0;

    return cal(a / b, b) + 1;
}
```